# async operation on DbContext

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

I may have a trivial question, but I'd better ask. I'm using .NET 7 and Entity Framework Core. Is it ok to do asynchronous queries on the database via `dbcontext`?

I'll give an example: I have 3 tables and I want to delete them. Logically, I don't care in which order I delete them and hence use asynchronicity. So I'll write something like:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
tasks.Add(_context.Orders.Delete()); //The delete method performs the deletion and calls save changes
tasks.Add(_context.Products.Delete());
tasks.Add(_context.Customer.Delete());
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Is that okay? Because I just read somewhere that asynchronous communication with `dbcontext` is not entirely appropriate and I don't want to break my application.

Because I've done it this way, but I still have in my head that I don't know if it's right, because then it opens more connections and as I said I've read that it's not really appropriate.

Thank you

Comment: `DbContext` is not thread-safe. Period.

Comment: @GertArnold Ok thank you. In the meantime i found this article https://www.davidguida.net/remember-kids-dbcontext-is-not-threadsafe/. So if i  mark dbocntext asi transiet thats ok no? But i think i don't want dbcontext as transient.

Comment: No. The question shows a misunderstanding of EF in general. A DbContext isn't a database connection, it's a Unit-of-Work. There's no database connection at all until you either try to load something, or save *all* pending changes with `SaveChangesAsync`. There's no `Delete` method, there's a `Remove` that only marks objects (and their owned relations) as `Deleted`. When you call `SaveChangesAsync` the DbContext collects all changes, generates the SQL commands and executes all of them asynchronously in a single database transaction

Comment: That means that the entire question is unclear. You can already query asynchronously with all the `To...Async` methods. You can already persist changes atomically and asynchronously with `SaveChangesAsync`. What's the actual problem?

Comment: `The delete method performs the deletion and calls save changes` then it's wrong. `SaveChangesAsync` persists *all* pending changes in all entities, which means that `Delete` could easily execute 42 INSERTs and 67 UPDATEs. `Remove` will also mark owned relations for deletion which means `Orders.Remove(...)` could also mark the related `OrderDetails` for deletion.

Comment: On top of that, it's unlikely parallelizing database access is going to save much time. Databases already are parallelized usually, up to the amount necessary, and they are primarily IO based so parallelizing more isn't going to do much other than slow down other operations.

Comment: To answer *So if i mark dbocntext asi transiet thats ok no?* -- Well, no. You still offer one context instance (`_context`) to multiple parallel threads. That has nothing to do with its life cycle in the DI container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to differentiate between asynchronous and parallelization. These concepts are related, but not one-in-the-same. Asynchronous code operates within parallelized (multi-threaded) environments and asynchronous code itself can be parallelized.

EF's `DbContext` does work perfectly fine with asynchronous code such as asynchhronous Linq methods and it exposes `async` methods, but it is not thread safe so it should never be parallelized, intentionally or accidentally. Any and all `async` methods involving a `DbContext` or other non-thread-safe instances must be awaited.

Methods like `Task.WaitAll()` are part of parallelization. The lifetime scope of a single injected `DbContext` (_context) will not matter, it represents a single instance and that instance cannot be safely used between parallel threads. If you do have a valid reason to parallelize `DbContext` operations then you want to scope an individual `DbContext` instance within the task. This is commonly done using a DbContext Factory pattern.

So not this:

```
tasks.Add(_context.Orders.Delete());
```

"_context" represents a single DbContext instance so adding two or more tasks to run operations against it in parallel is a big no-no. Instead:

```
tasks.Add(deleteOrders());
```

then:

```
private async Task deleteOrders()
{
    using var context = _contextFactory.Create();
    context.Orders.Delete(); //Whatever operations against the context DbSets etc.
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Your controller or service or whatever can still have a `DbContext` instance (_context) injected and scoped to the `HttpRequest` or other lifetime scope, but be sure that instance is never used within parallelized code. Instead it would also have a `DbContext` Factory class (_contextFactory) injected that can create new transient `DbContext` instances for parallelized code. That `DbContext` instance will be specific and disposed within the scope of the task code.